# iOS how to upload a large asset file into sever by streaming

Tags: ios, upload, streaming

I am new iOS programmer.
I want to upload a large file(video or image) from **asset library** into sever,
My original way is just use **NSMutableURLRequest** and append **NSData**(large video or large image) to it, and crash happened in the following code:

```
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *asset){
        //.......some code I just skip it...
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        void *buffer = [rawData mutableBytes];
        [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0 length:size error:nil];
        NSData *videoData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:size];//crash here
        [self startUploading:videoData];
    }
```

I know this crash is because memory is not enough, video file can't just alloc to NSData.
 
I've google this for 2 days, and sounds there are several ways to solve this.

1. use third party library: such like AFNetworking, ASIHTTPRequest(but I don't want to use it,because don't know when will this stop maintaining or updating )
2. use streaming to upload large file

and I want to use streaming way(point 2) to do upload stuff,
I found this link:  http://zh.scribd.com/doc/51504708/10/Upload-Files-Over-HTTP
Look like can solve my problem, but still not very clear to know how to do

**Question1**:
there is an example in that link, the upload file is from bundle
how to make asset into stream? or copy asset to APP's folder?
I found this link [Copy image from assets-library to an app folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967549/copy-image-from-assets-library-to-an-app-folder)
 but still can not find the way.

**Question2**:
or Is there any other more clear streaming example for uploading large file?

Thank you for your passion 

**updated1**: after I implemented needNewBodyStream delegate,  "request stream exhaustion" message seemed to solved, but instead, meet another "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn't be completed." how to solve it?

```
-(NSInputStream *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection needNewBodyStream:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    NSInputStream *fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:pathToBodyFile];
    if (fileStream == nil) {
        NSLog(@"NSURLConnection was asked to retransmit a new body stream for a request. returning nil!");
    }
    return fileStream;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your data is too big to fit into memory:

An effective and reliable approach would utilize a bounded pair of CFStreams (see [CFStreamCreateBoundPair](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003362-CH5-F17772)).

The bounded stream pair's *input stream* is set to the `NSMutableURLRequest`'s `HTTPBodyStream` property. The bounded stream pair's *output stream* will be used to write bytes obtained from a fixed size memory buffer which has been filled with `ALAssetRepresentation`'s `getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:` method.

The size of the bounded stream pair's transfer-buffer should be the same as the size of the buffer for the asset representation.

Setting up the code will require a couple lines of code and some experience with NSStreams and handling the events (there are often a few subtleties with NSStreams).

This approach works as follows:

1. Create a stream's delegate which handles all stream events.
2. Setup the paired streams with a particular size for the transfer buffer, setup the delegate and schedule them on a run loop.
3. Setup a memory buffer for the asset data with the same size.
4. When you opened the streams, you get a `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` event. You handle that event by reading from the asset data via `getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:`, and write into the memory buffer. When you filled your buffer with a chunk of the asset data, write this buffer into the bounded stream pair's *output stream*. Track offsets appropriately!
5. Now, the bounded streams pair's *input stream* well be extracted by the underlaying connection (which moves bytes from the internal transfer-buffer to the network socket), and you will get another `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` event, since now space is available in the internal transfer-buffer. Write as much bytes as fit into the bounded stream pair's *output stream* from your asset data buffer to *output stream* and as much bytes are available in your asset data buffer. If the asset data buffer has been written completely, refill it. Carefully track offsets and ranges!
6. You handle the events until the the whole asset data has been written. Then close the output stream.
7. You will need to handle other stream events as well, see: [Stream Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188-SW1)

Note: you may notice that your memory buffer can only be *partially* written to the output stream. Take care of this by *tracking offsets* so that you always keep a continuos stream of asset data in your buffer and write the appropriate range of data from your buffer to the output stream!

#### Caveat:

Setting up a correct implementation withe a bounded pair of streams may be tricky and is perhaps error prone. I do have a generic version of a "InputStreamSource" (which exposes an ordinary NSInputStream which will be used to setup the HTTPBodyStream property) which can be easily extended to be used with any source of input - e.g. the asset data. I may put this code on gist, if you are interested.

AFNetworking or any other network library will *not* solve that for you. And to be honest, I wouldn't recommend to use AFNetworking in conjunction with a *stream* as the *body part* - since the implementation of AFNetworking is still suspect in this regard. I would recommend to use `NSURLConnection` with implementing the delegates yourself, or use another third party library which handles input body streams for POST requests correctly.

#### A Short (incomplete) Example

The idea is, to create some sort of "asset input source" class which exposes a `NSInputStream` (which can be used to set the `HTTPBodyStream` property of the `NSURLRequest`) and provides the asset data.

If the "asset input source" were a file, the task would be easy: just create a `NSInputStream` object associated to that file. However, our asset can be accessed only via a range of bytes in a certain representation, which resides in some temporary buffer.

So, the task is to fill that temporary buffer with the appropriate range of bytes. Then, piecewise, write those bytes into a private *output stream* which is bound to an *input stream*. This *input stream* and *output stream* pair will be created via function `CFStreamCreateBoundPair`.

The *input stream* will become our *exposed NSInputStream* of the "asset input source".

The *output stream* is used internally only. The "asset input source" will be initialized with the asset.

Our "asset input source" class needs to handle stream events, thus it will become a stream delegate.

Now, we have everything to implement it.

The `CFStreamCreateBoundPair` function creates CFStream objects. However, since NSStreams are [toll-free bridged](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html) we can easily "convert" them to NSStreams.

Part of a `start` or an `init` method of the "asset input source" class can be implemented as follows:

```
    _buffer = (uint8_t)malloc(_bufferSize);
    _buffer_end = _buffer + _bufferSize;
    _p = _buffer;
    CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
    CFStreamCreateBoundPair(NULL, &readStream, &writeStream, _bufferSize);
    self.inputStream = CFBridgingRelease(readStream);
    self.internalOutputStream = CFBridgingRelease(writeStream);        

    [self.internalOutputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:self.runLoopMode];
    [self.internalOutputStream open];
    // (Note: inputStream will be opened and scheduled by the request!)
```

`inputStream` is a public @property of that class (the exposed input stream).

`internalOutputStream` is a *private* property of the class.

`_buffer` is the internal buffer holding a range of bytes of the asset representation.

Note that the bounded stream pair's internal buffer size is equal to the buffer holding the asset data.

The stream delegate method `stream:handleEvent:` can be implemented as shown below:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
    if (_isCancelled) {
        return;
    }
    switch (streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventNone:
            break;
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            DLogInfo(@"internal output stream: open completed");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            // n.a.
            NSAssert(0, @"bogus stream event");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            NSAssert(theStream == _internalOutputStream, @"bogus stream event");
            DLogInfo(@"destination stream: has space available");
            [self write];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            DLogInfo(@"destination stream: error occurred");
            [self finish];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            // weird error: the output stream is full or closed prematurely, or canceled.
            DLogWarn(@"destination stream: EOF encountered");
            if (_result == nil) {
                self.result = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSStringFromClass([self class])
                                                  code:-2
                                              userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"output stream EOF encountered"}];
            }
            [self finish];
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the secret is in method `write`. There is also a `finish` method and a `cancel` method.

Basically, method `write` copies from the _buffer into the internal output stream, as much as fit into the stream. When _buffer is completely written into the output stream, it will be filled again from the asset data.

When there is no more data available to write from the asset to the output stream, method `finish` is invoked.

Method `finish` closes the internal output stream and unschedules the stream.

A complete and reliable implementation may be a bit tricky. The "asset input source" should also be cancelable.

As mentioned, I do have an "abstract input source" class, which implements everything except the filling of _buffer with asset data, which I can provide as a code snippet on Gist, if you want.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I feel confused about:1.you mentioned CFSteams but in point 4 you said NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable event. are those two different class? how can I　use CFStream and also set the delegate to fire  NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable event? and please share your code, thank you so much

Comment: Well, I told you: "Setting up a correct implementation with a bounded pair of streams may be tricky" ;)  I will update my answer and give a brief example.

Comment: Really thank you for your sharing, and I have think about what you said: " our asset can be accessed only via a range of bytes in a certain representation, which resides in some temporary buffer.", if I can copy asset to APP folder like:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961534/uploading-large-nsdata-to-the-web and then I only need to use NSStream for uploading right?

Comment: and please provide as a code snippet on Gist for me, it will help me a lot! Thank you soooooo much!!!

Comment: I don't know whether it's possible to copy or access the asset file (due to restrictions in the sandbox) - but you may give it a try. So, check that - and IFF it's possible, then you can create an NSInputStream from this file. Caveat here: you cannot specify a certain predefined asset representation - you get whatever format the file is (possibly a some raw format).

Comment: I'm currently writing a brief example. It takes me a while, since all of the network requirements, like cancellation, resetting of the input stream, etc.. A requirement for that "input source stream", especially when this is a large input source, is that it is cancelable and also "reset-able" which is required when you get a redirection response. I do have an implementation, but it is especially tailored for my (private) network library. So, the task is now to make it usable without the common stuff it depends on. Please stay patient ...   ;)

Comment: if there is not enough storage on device, like 100 mb left, and I upload a file over 100 mb by using stream, does it work?

Comment: Using streams avoids to copy the whole data into memory. Usually, a stream internally uses a fixed size transfer buffer where it reads from source and writes to the destination. Exceptions are - for example - memory streams, which are just an abstraction over a NSMutableData.

Comment: hi,currently,I met a log showed "request body stream exhausted", what dose this message mean? I've checked content-length in header,it's correct (same as the size of uploading file) but still don't know how to solve this, do you know is there any possible place that I missed?

Comment: This most likely means, that a request has been started with sending a body stream, but a redirect response has been received. In that case, the request needs to be repeated with using the redirect URL (NSURLConnection will do that automatically). The stream however cannot be _reset_ automatically. You need to override the delegate `connection:needNewBodyStream:` where you set `HTTPBodyStream` again with a newly created stream. (NSStreams cannot be re-winded).

Comment: Hi, I just did what you said, implemented 'connection:needNewBodyStream:', **and request stream exhaustion** message was gone now, but instead, another message showed(please look my updated 1), I've searched the message for"The operation couldn't be completed", look like this happened by get/post or wrong Jason format. But I don't think those reason cause the "The operation couldn't be completed" problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: From file "CFNetworkErrors.h":code 303 means `kCFErrorHTTPParseFailure`, "The HTTP server response could not be parsed". This is something quite unusual. So, without more details, e.g. HTTP packet traces, I cannot tell what's going wrong here and where.

Comment: In order to verify _your_ code, you should now simplify your setup, e.g. use a `NSData` object as request body, then a file input stream from a local file whose size is relative small. Check ALL errors in your code and ALL return values that you can get and log them to the console. Generously sprinkle your code with assertions to confirm that the code behaves as you expect. Basically, there are many reasons why network code will not work. So basically, try to locate the error more precisely. Possibly ask a NEW question on SO, with more related details for this error.

Comment: hi, I asked a new question, please take a look, really thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042503/upload-file-by-streamming-shows-error-log-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed

Comment: @Rob please invite me into a chat, since a thorough explanation takes more than a few lines.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Please join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44824/afnetworking-streaming

Comment: @CouchDeveloper will this work for NSURLSession in Background?
My question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325169/nsurlsession-background-file-upload-using-bound-streams

Answer (score 0):

I have a swift version of converting `ALAsset` to `NSInputStream` via `CFStreamCreateBoundPair` which implements what the top answer describes called [ALAssetToNSInputStream](https://github.com/luowenxing/ALAssetToNSInputStream).Check it out if needed.