# NSURLSession Background File Upload using Bound Streams

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, nsurlsession, nsstream

**History:**

I am working on a project for which we need to support:

- Background Upload of files using `NSURLSession`.
- The server expects file to be uploaded using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`
- Previously, I was using `NSURLConnection` with bound pair of Streams as depicted in this [Apple Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Listings/PostController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245-PostController_m-DontLinkElementID_12).
- Now, I wish to follow similar approach with `NSURLSession(Background Session)` by using `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest`:.
- I have written a small stand-alone iOS Sample + a PHP server to validate my concept.

**Problem:** Everything works if app stays in foreground, but if during upload I press the home key, the upload fails after some time with error:

> Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service"

Also a little before the upload fails the Write/Producer Stream's `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` is encountered.

**Note:** I know the work-around where I can write whole HTTP Post body to a temp file and use `NSURLSession's` file upload API instead. But above is more appropriate if I can make it work.

**Question:** Can anyone guess what could be possible reason for the upload getting failed?

**Sample Code:** I have uploaded the iOS Sample Code + PHP Server Code to drop box. Here is the [CODE](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/un2jqxhbhya8jr3/AACXkwUYkgYj2IN0cfVUGZida?dl=0)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting up the session as a "Background Session"? See [+ (NSURLSessionConfiguration *)backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSessionConfiguration/backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload streamed tasks using Background Configuration. I successfully upload data only in two cases:

1. Download task with data stored in request body.
2. Upload task from file. In that case you will not receive response body.

Comment: What you wrote is true for iOS 7. But for iOS 8+ you can use data tasks and background session.

Comment: @Shmidt yes, but they can't be streamed data tasks (as stated in Apple docs): 
* Only upload tasks from a file are supported (uploading from data objects or a stream will fail after the program exits).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed that it's about streams.